# Can I create a type based on characters within a string

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a 2 character string and expands it to a full property. For example it'll take `mr` and return `MarginRight` or `pt` and return `PaddingTop`.

My question here is how would one go about typing such a function? basically I want to limit the first character of the input string to `m` or `p` and the second character to `r`, `l`, `t`, or `b`. So far I just have `([marginOrPadding, direction]: string): string` but that obviously will accept a lot more than I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this a finite and relatively low number of items you can use overloads, or you can use an interface to map the input strings to the output type and use that in your function signature:

```
interface Abbreviations {
    "mr" : "MarginRight"
    "pr" : "PaddingRight"
    // and the rest 
}
function expand<K extends keyof Abbreviations>(k: K): Abbreviations[K] {
    return null!;
}

expand("mr") // retruns MarginRight
expand("SS") // error
```

You could use also keep the abbreviations in an object and use the type of that instead, if yo don't already have an implementation:

```
function withLiterals<
    T extends Record<string, V>, 
    V extends string | boolean | number | symbol | null | undefined | Record<string, V>
>(input: T ): T { return input }
const abbreviations = withLiterals({
    "mr" : "MarginRight",
    "pr" : "PaddingRight"
    // and the rest 
})
function expand<K extends keyof typeof abbreviations>(k: K): typeof abbreviations[K] {
    return null!;
}

expand("mr") // retruns MarginRight
expand("SS") // error
```